# Google Analytics for Firebase events as conversions in Google Ads not working for Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-ads-api, firebase-analytics

After Importing our Firebase app events in Google Ads as conversions, their status stays at "no recent conversions". The events are recording fine in Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The "No recent conversions" status indicates that Google Ads is able to track your conversion tracking tag, but it didn't capture any data in the last 7 days. I would suggest giving time for your data to populate. You can read more on this status at this [link](https://support.google.com/google-ads/troubleshooter/10028419?hl=en&visit_id=638060295256166357-2881528895&rd=1#ts=10029493).